# Why isn't media query updating values after they are changed via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I have a pretty standard navigation bar, with a list containing the links to my sub-sites. I have added a hamburger-menu icon to the website, which should appear on small and mobile screens. Also, I hide the links, by setting their font-size to zero via the css media query. If the menu icon is clicked I fire a javascript function, that will increase/decrease the fontsize of the links accordingly.

All of this works pretty nicely, there is only one issue. As soon as I resize my browser after the font-size of the links has been changed by the script, those values are kept and not updated by the media query for some reason. So, depending on whether the mobile menu was open or closed, the fontsize is either extremely big, or zero. Why aren't these values updated when resizing the browser back to full-screen?

**code-snippet containing the necessary code to reproduce:**

```js
var open = false;

function openmobilemenu() {
    var nav = document.getElementsByTagName("nav");
    var links = nav[0].getElementsByTagName("li");
    if (!open) {
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            links[i].style.transition = "0.5s";
            links[i].style.fontSize = "10vw";
        }
        open = true;
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            links[i].style.fontSize = "0";
        }
        open = false;
    }
}
```

```css
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url("../img/header.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-color: #CDCCCA;
}

    header img {
        position: absolute;
        width: 500px;
        padding: 0 15%;
        bottom: 10px;
    }

.mobilemenu {
    display: none;
}



nav {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #61625B;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

    nav ul {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 70%;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0 15%;
        display: flex;
        margin: 0;
    }

    nav li {
        width: 125px;
        text-align: center;
        transition: none;
    }

.navunderline {
    width: 125px;
    height: 0;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    background-color: #DAD9D7;
    transition: 500ms;
}

nav a {
    color: #DAD9D7;
}

    nav a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

nav li:hover .navunderline {
    height: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 800px), (hover:none) {

    .mobilemenu {
        display: flex;
        color: #61625B;
        font-size: 100px;
        margin: auto 5%;
    }

        .mobilemenu a, a:hover, a:active {
            text-decoration: none;
        }



    nav {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #61625B;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 10px;
        height: auto;
        overflow: visible;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

        nav ul {
            position: relative;
            height: auto;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            list-style: none;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 0;
        }

        nav li {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 0;
            height: auto;
        }

            nav li:hover {
                background-color: #8b131f;
            }

    .navunderline {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

 
 <header>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="some alt" /></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="mobilemenu" onclick="openmobilemenu()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
    </header>
    
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="content/unternehmen.html">Unternehmen</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
            <li><a href="content/leistungen.html">Leistungen</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
            <li><a href="content/referenzen.html">Referenzen</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
            <li><a href="content/news.html">News</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
            <li><a href="content/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a><div class="navunderline"></div></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your JS is setting inline styles on your elements and inline styles are always more specific than anything in your stylesheet.

There are three ways around this:

1. Use JS on window resize to remove those styles.
2. Don't inline styles, but add/remove classes on those elements on resize. Use your stylesheet to control the styles for those elements.
3. Set the font styles to `!important` in your stylesheet (the only way around specificity - **not recommended**)

Comment: Ahh, thank you @disinfor. I guess the second suggestion is going to be the best option since I have seen it done this way on w3 schools and always wondered, why they add extra classes.